# ¿Como controlar el bug para cuando se ingrese un dato de tipo char cuando el programa pide un int en C++?

Tags: c++

Cuando en mi programa solicito unas coordenadas que son de tipo int, y por accidente, el usuario ingresa un carácter, el programa repite el proceso en donde se pide al usuario el numero infinitamente.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Añade tu código para que los usuarios te puedan ayudar correctamente por favor!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`cin` establece el `failbit` cuando se inserta un tipo inválido de dato, por lo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Inserta un dato: " << endl;
    cin >> x;

    if (!cin) 
        cout << "tipo CHAR";
    else
        cout << "tipo INT";

    return 0;
}
```

También puedes utilizar `cin.fail()` para comprobar si tu dato de entrada es válido de la siguiente forma:

```
if ( cin.fail() ) {
    // dato de entrada NO válido
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que verificar cada entrada del usuario, nunca confíes en el.

Esto lo puedes hacer de 2 formas:

## 1. En caso de error, limpiando el stream

La forma en la que ves si ha habido algún problema es casteando `std::cin` a un
booleano, o llamando a `fail`.

Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int numero = 0;
    std::cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
    std::cin >> numero;

    bool lectura_correcta = static_cast<bool>(std::cin); // !std::cin.fail()
    if (lectura_correcta) {
        std::cout << "Se leyo correctamente\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Lo que ingreso no es un entero\n";
    }

    // Si lo metes en el if, el cast es implicito, puedes reescribirlo como:
    // if (std::cin) {
    //     std::cout << "Se leyo correctamente\n";
    // } else {
    //     std::cout << "Lo que ingreso no es un entero\n";
    // }
}
```

Si encontraste algún error al leer, tienes que saber que `std::cin` no cambia
nada en el stream de entrada.

Si el usuario ingresa:

```
Hola
```

Y tu tratas de leer un entero, cuando falle no se tocara el stream, va
a esperar a que tu manualmente lo limpies. Eso significa que si tratas de leer
un entero otra vez, te volverás a topar con el `Hola`.

Y como se limpia el stream? Por suerte, `std::cin` tiene la función `ignore`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> // Nota el nuevo header

int main(void) {
    int numero = 0;
    std::cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
    std::cin >> numero;

    if (std::cin) {
        std::cout << "Se leyo correctamente\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Lo que ingreso no es un entero\n";

        std::cin.clear(); // Indica que ya no hay errores
        // Ignora todos los caracteres hasta toparse con una linea nueva
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        
        // ...
        // Ahora ya puedes intentar leer
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ya tomando esto en cuenta, podemos hacer una función que lea un entero, y si
falla, que limpie el stream y vuelva a pedir otro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

static int get_int(void) {
    int n = 0;
    std::cout << "Ingrese un entero: ";
    while (!(std::cin >> n)) { // (std::cin >> n) retorna std::cin, asi que
                               // podemos hacer este shortcut

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Tiene que ingresar un numero entero: ";
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    const int numero = get_int();

    std::cout << "El numero es: " << numero << '\n';
}
```

O cuando ya tengas algo mas de experiencia, puedes escribir la función solo una
vez y usar templates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <typename T>
T formated_read(const std::string& prompt, const std::string& err_msg = "") {
    T n{};
    std::cout << prompt;
    while (!(std::cin >> n)) { // (std::cin >> n) retorna std::cin, asi que
                               // podemos hacer este shortcut

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (!err_msg.empty()) {
            std::cout << err_msg;
        } else {
            std::cout << prompt;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    const int numero = formated_read<int>("Ingrese un numero entero: ");
    const float flotante = formated_read<float>("Ingrese un numero con decimales: ");

    std::cout << "El numero es: " << numero << '\n';
    std::cout << "El float es: " << flotante << '\n';
}
```

## 2. Leer una cadena, y revisar esta cadena

Este seria mi método preferido, ya que no pierdes la entrada el usuario en caso de que aun pueda serte de utilidad (ej. puedes indicarle en que punto en especifico no esta cumpliendo con el formato de entrada).

La estrategia seria la siguiente, leer una linea, y ejecutar el mismo
procedimiento que hicimos arriba. Solo que en este caso en lugar de hacer la
extracción formateada de `std::cin`, crearemos un stream específicamente para
eso.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // Nota los nuevos headers
#include <sstream>

static int get_int(void) {
    int n = 0;

    std::cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";

    std::string ingresado;
    std::getline(std::cin, ingresado); // Leemos una linea
    std::stringstream ss(ingresado); // Creamos el stream con lo que nos
                                     // dieron

    if (ss >> n) { // Si se pudo leer, lo retornamos
        return n;
    }

    // Y si no lo pedimos otra vez
    std::cout << "Tiene que ingresar un numero entero\n";
    return get_int();
}

int main(void) {
    const int numero = get_int();

    std::cout << "El numero es: " << numero << '\n';
}
```

Este tiene la ventaja de que también atrapa líneas en blanco.

```
Ingrese un numero: l
Tiene que ingresar un numero entero
Ingrese un numero:
Tiene que ingresar un numero entero
Ingrese un numero: 3
El numero es: 3
```

La generalización de esta ultima se la dejo de tarea al lector.