# Evitar error al introducir un string o char en un Int, float o double... C++

Tags: c++, string, float, double, interfaz

Este no es una pregunta, solo quiero compartirles la solución que le di a este problema, pues en mi universidad nos están obligando a que el programa no se caiga de ninguna manera así que decidí buscarle una solución a este problema tan común y se la comparto a quien la necesite ;D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

//____________________________________________
// Como evitar error al digitar un tipo
// de dato erroneo en un int, double, float...
//____________________________________________
// Se recomienda usar dentro de una interfaz
//____________________________________________

bool leerEntero(int& valor) { // Recibe el valor por referencia
    bool esEntero;

    cin >> valor;            // Lee ese valor por referencia
    esEntero = cin.good();   // Comprueba si su lectura fue correcta

    if(!esEntero){           // En caso de que no, ignorará ese Cin 
       cin.clear();          // para evitar errores.
    
       cin.ignore(numeric_limits < streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }                        // Lo ultimo se asegura de leer e ignorar TODOS
    return esEntero;         // los caracteres para que se ejecute bien, es total
}                            // -mente necesario.   

int main() {
    int valor;               // Funciona tambien con otros tipos de datos

    cout<< endl << " Digite un valor entero: ";

    while(!leerEntero(valor)){                // Lee y verifica 
        cout << endl << " Ese valor no es valido.";
        cout << endl << " Digite de nuevo: "; // Vuelve al while y repite la lectura
    }                                         // hasta que sea un entero

    cout << endl << " Su valor es: " << valor << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que les haya servido. Cualquier duda puedo intentar atenderla ;D

Comment: No lo pongas aquí como pregunta, te podrían sancionar por ello, súbelo a github para que personas realmente interesadas lo puedan encontrar más fácilmente.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una preguntaq

Comment: Formula la pregunta y despues escribe tu respuesta para enseñar su solución a este problema.

Comment: Tu solución esta bien, pero la forma en la que lo presentas no va de acuerdo al formato del sitio. Deja la parte de arriba como una pregunta, y luego publica abajo la solución que tu le diste. Nótese que cabe la posibilidad de que te la cierren, ya que creo que seria un duplicado de [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489122/como-controlar-el-bug-para-cuando-se-ingrese-un-dato-de-tipo-char-cuando-el-pro/489146).