# Bucle Infinito al introducir un dato de tipo "char"

Tags: c++, bucles, números-primos

Estaba haciendo un pequeño programa para calcular la factorización de un número y quería que la entrada fuese exactamente un número entero, y que el usuario no pudiera meter otro tipo de dato. La cosa es que cuando se introduce un "`char`" el programa se vuelve loco y entra en un bucle infinito. Parece que lo he solucionado un poco usando "`scanf(tipo_dato,&variable)`" pero aún así el código sigue fallando en determinadas ocasiones.

Estoy estudiando y puede que el código no sea lo mejor (incluso que os dé dolor de ojos) por eso si alguno tiene alguna sugerencia sobre como podría depurar el código, se lo agradecería.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool correcto(int n){
    bool h = true;
    h =  n <= 999999 && n > 0 ;

    if (h == false ){
        cout << "Introduzca un número correcto porfavor\n";
    }

    return h;
}

int nextPrimo (int num){

    bool esPrimo = false;
    int  numero = num+1;
    int divisores = 2;
    
    while(!esPrimo){

        for(int i = 2;i<=numero/2;i++){
            
            if(numero % i == 0){
                divisores++;
            }

        } 

        if (divisores == 2 ) {
            esPrimo = true;
        }else {
            numero++;
            divisores = 2;
        }
    }

    return numero;

}

void factorizacion (int n){

    int primo = 2;

    cout << "La factorización de "<<n<<" es:\n\n";

    while (n > 1){
        
        if (n % primo == 0){
            if(n >= 100000){
                cout << n<<"| "<<primo<<"\n";
            }
            else if(n >= 10000 && n <= 99999){
                cout << n<<" | "<<primo<<"\n";
            }else if(n >= 1000 && n <= 9999){
                cout << n<<"  | "<<primo<<"\n";
            }else if(n >= 100 && n <= 999){
                cout << n<<"   | "<<primo<<"\n";
            }else if(n >= 10 && n <= 99){
                cout << n<<"    | "<<primo<<"\n";
            }else if ( n != 0){
                cout << n<<"     | "<<primo<<"\n";
            }
            n = n/primo;
        }else{
            primo = nextPrimo(primo);
        }

    }

    cout<<"1     | "<<"\n\n";

}

int main() {
   
    int numero;
    bool cont = true;
    char sig;
    do{

        do{

            cout << "\nIntroduzca el número a factorizar: ";
            
            if (scanf("%i",&numero) != 1){
                cout<<"Entrada no númerica\n\n";
                numero = 1;
            }


        }while(!correcto(numero));

    if (numero != 1) {
        factorizacion(numero);  
    }

        cout << "¿Quiere seguir usando el programa? (s/n) ";
        cin>>sig;

        if(sig == 'n') cont = false;

    }while(cont);


    return 0;

}
```

El código no es lo más eficiente del mundo porque pretendo que la salida sea similar a como se hace cuando uno lo aprenda.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como controlar el bug para cuando se ingrese un dato de tipo char cuando el programa pide un int en C++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489122/como-controlar-el-bug-para-cuando-se-ingrese-un-dato-de-tipo-char-cuando-el-pro). Como una nota, no uses `scanf`. Primero porque estas en C++, `scanf` es de C. Y segundo, `scanf` es probablemente la peor forma de leer entrada de el usuario que existe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ante un fallo en la lectura, el buffer de entrada **no se ve modificado**. Es decir, si tu intentas leer un entero y en el buffer de entrada hay un caracter no numérico, ese caracter se quedará ahí *ad eternum* o hasta que decidas extraer ese caracter por otros medios.

Por comentarios te están sugiriendo no usar `scanf` y ese comentario tiene sus motivos. `scanf` es una función heredada de C. La I/O de C es bastante engorrosa y propensa a errores. Es preferible usar la I/O propia de C++:

Así pues lo recomendable aquí sería reemplazar el uso de `scanf` por el de `cin`. Ahora bien, cuando la lectura de `cin` falla se activará un flag interno de error y esto provoca que `cin` se *cuelgue* hasta que dicho flag se reinicie. Lo que tenemos que hacer entonces es reiniciar el flag de error y borrar lo que haya en el buffer de entrada:

```
int value;
std::cin >> value;
if (std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();                                  // Se resetea el flag de erorr
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());  // Se limpia el buffer
}
```

Por otro lado, te comento una características de C++ que puede mejorar la legibilidad de tu programa.

**Formateando la salida - iomanip**

La librería `iomanip` tiene una serie de utilidades que permiten dar formato a la salida de datos. Una de esas utilidades tiene como finalidad el dar un tamaño mínimo a cada campo, lo que permite tabular cómodamente los resultados:

```
std::cout << std::setw(6) << std::left << n << " | " << primo << '\n';
```

Esta línea reemplaza al siguiente código:

```
        if(n >= 100000){
            cout << n<<"| "<<primo<<"\n";
        }
        else if(n >= 10000 && n <= 99999){
            cout << n<<" | "<<primo<<"\n";
        }else if(n >= 1000 && n <= 9999){
            cout << n<<"  | "<<primo<<"\n";
        }else if(n >= 100 && n <= 999){
            cout << n<<"   | "<<primo<<"\n";
        }else if(n >= 10 && n <= 99){
            cout << n<<"    | "<<primo<<"\n";
        }else if ( n != 0){
            cout << n<<"     | "<<primo<<"\n";
        }
```

Si quisieses alinear `n` a la derecha, lo cual suele ser la opción habitual al imprimir números, bastaría con quitar `std::left`.