# No encuentro la forma de invalidar un ingreso de dato erróneo

Tags: c++, validación, input, números-enteros

Le estoy pidiendo al usuario que me ingrese un dato tipo **número**, para yo poder realizar operaciones con el después (pero yo lo almaceno en un **string**, para que no me muestre error si el usuario digita algo que no es un número).

Este dato almacenado lo convierto en **int**, pero el problema esta en que si el dato no es un numero me dice *argumento invalido* al momento de hacer la conversión.

En otras palabras, no encuentro la manera de que el programa no me genere ningun tipo de error si el usuario ingresó un dato erróneo, para que en vez de fallar me diga que lo digitado es incorrecto.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte. Lo que buscas se llama validación de datos, te dejo un ejemplo en las respuestas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como controlar el bug para cuando se ingrese un dato de tipo char cuando el programa pide un int en C++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489122/como-controlar-el-bug-para-cuando-se-ingrese-un-dato-de-tipo-char-cuando-el-pro)

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Lo que buscas se llama validación de datos de entrada y existen varios métodos para hacerlo

Podrías utilizar un `while` para evaluar si la entrada es numérica o no

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int numero;

    while(!(cin >> numero)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cout << "Debes ingresar un valor numérico, intenta de nuevo." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```