# Como comprobar si el ingreso de una variable string, es un numero. (C++)

Tags: c++, excepciones

Hola quiero validar una toma de datos en C++ usando manejo de excepciones (try, catch, throw). Hasta el momento solo se validar lo que serian los numeros ya sea int o float, pero no sabria como hacer para validar los strings. Suponiendo que al pedir el nombre, el usuario escribe 1234, ahí deberia lanzar un error. Lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
void Persona::pedir() {
try{
cout << "Ingrese su DNI: ";
cin >> dni;
cout << "Ingrese su NOMBRE: ";
cin >> nombre;
cout << "Ingrese su MAIL: ";
cin >> mail;
cout << "Ingrese su EMPRESA: ";
cin >> empresa;
cout << "Ingrese su SUELDO: ";
cin >> sueldo;
if (dni<0)throw 0;
if (sueldo<1))throw 1;
}
catch (int error){
cout<<"Error: ";
if (error ==0)cout<<"El numero de dni debe ser mayor a 0";
if (error ==1)cout<<"El sueldo debe ser mayor a 1";
}
}
```

Comment: Puede que la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489122/como-controlar-el-bug-para-cuando-se-ingrese-un-dato-de-tipo-char-cuando-el-pro/489146#489146) te pueda ser de utilidad.

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias por tu respuesta. En realidad deberia implementarlo con excepciones usando try, catch, throw. No variables tipo bool.

Comment: Entonces puedes crear una función para validarlo, y lanzar una excepción en caso de que la entrada no sea valida. Si recibes una excepción, repite el proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Ya existe un metodo en c++ para determinar lo que necesitas

```
isAlpha();
isDigit();
```

requieren incluir la libreria de:

```
 <ctype.h>

char valor1 = 'a';
char valor2 = '1';
if(isAlpha(valor1))... //Retorna true
if(isAlpha(valor2))... //Retorna false

char valor1 = 1;
char valor2 = '1';
char valor3 = 'b';

if(isNUmber(valor1))... //Retorna true
if(isNUmber(valor2))... //Retorna true
if(isNumber(valor3))... //Retorna false
```

Comment: me podrias dar un ejemplo aplicandolo al codigo mio? Por ejemplo con la variable nombre.

Comment: Implemente lo siguiente: if (isdigit(nombre))throw 2; ------- me tira error "No matching function for call to isDigit"

Comment: disculpa no entro muy seguido. https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-number-cpp/ revisa este enlace puede que te sea de utilidad, aplica lo que te mencionaba

Answer (score 0):

Por puntos:

1. No puedes asumir que el nombre de una persona sólo contendrá letras ya que existen personas como [Jennifer 8. Lee](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8._Lee).
2. No puedes limitar los datos que pueden entrar en un `std::string`, ya que cualquier dato es potencialmente convertible a texto.
3. Se considera mala práctica lanzar como excepciones datos que no deriven de `std::exception`.

Suponiendo que el primer punto no existiese, para solventar el segundo punto [podrías leer un número y si no falla su lectura lo consideras un error](https://tio.run/##XY/LasMwEEXXmq@Ypht7kUL6yEuuN/2NQlHkcRDIo6DHqvjbHdkRNM1CIM69c@@MvlzW2io@T9OzYW1TR9gYF6InNbTwxzIxfG4BDEcclOGqhl8QIXbH401DdsPJkwQQvfNYnZyzhf1YMp3DT@yVDSTx6R5LrEHkKDEncxrIuzlDmB6rJV4bxrYtUvYu5luzdili0xRt/q1yJVLAxKX7m1cy@8f8KJf/Hzf8oi0pX9XyHi515ZqMH46IPlGJHAEeFilT4zRtXt/g/WMLu/0BvlRQ3HkFVw):

```
std::string nombre;

for (bool nombre_leido = false; !nombre_leido; )
{
        int numero;

        if (std::cin >> numero)
        {
            std::cout << numero << " no es un nombre\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> nombre;
            nombre_leido = true;
        }
}
```

Para solventar el tercer punto, cambia tus `throw` por excepciones estándar.

---

Siguiendo los consejos anteriores, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
string pedir_solo_texto()
{
    std::string texto;

    for (bool nombre_leido = false; !nombre_leido; )
    {
        int numero;

        if (std::cin >> numero)
        {
            std::cout << numero << " no es texto\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> texto;
            nombre_leido = true;
        }
    }

    return texto;
}

struct dni_incorrecto : public std::exception {};
struct sueldo_incorrecto : public std::exception {};

void Persona::pedir() try { // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block
    std::cout << "Ingrese su DNI: ";
    std::cin >> dni;
    if (dni < 0) throw dni_incorrecto(std::format("el DNI {} no es valido", dni));

    std::cout << "Ingrese su NOMBRE: ";
    nombre = pedir_solo_texto();

    std::cout << "Ingrese su MAIL: ";
    std::cin >> mail;

    std::cout << "Ingrese su EMPRESA: ";
    std::cin >> empresa;

    std::cout << "Ingrese su SUELDO: ";
    std::cin >> sueldo;
    if (sueldo < 1) throw sueldo_incorrecto(std::format("el sueldo {} no es valido", sueldo));
}
catch (const dni_incorrecto &e) {
    // ...
}
catch (const sueldo_incorrecto &e) {
    // ...
}
```