# como puedo hacer para cuando se ingresa una letra en un tipo de dato double y no se cierre o bloquee el programa en c++

Tags: c++

como puedo hacer para imprimir un mensaje de invalidacion por pantalla cuando se ingresa una letra en un tipo de dato double y que no se boque o cierre el programa.

```
{
    double N1,N2;   
    
    cout<<"ingrese un numero:\n\n"; 
    cin>>N1;    
    cout<<"ingrese otro numero:\n\n";
    cin>>N2;
    if(N1<N2) 
    {        
        cout<<"el numero mayor es:"<<N2;  
        cout<<"\n el numero menor es:"<<N1<<endl;
    }
    if (N1>N2)  
    {           
        cout<<"el numero menor es:"<<N2<<endl;
        cout<<"el numero mayor es:"<<N1<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: En realidad el programa espera hasta que introduzcas un número. Lo que podrías hacer es tomar la entrada como string y realizar la conversión al tipo deseado. De ese modo cuando se presione enter el programa dejará de esperar entrada sin importar el contenido. En este caso puedes usar la función [`stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) para la conversión.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como controlar el bug para cuando se ingrese un dato de tipo char cuando el programa pide un int en C++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489122/como-controlar-el-bug-para-cuando-se-ingrese-un-dato-de-tipo-char-cuando-el-pro)

Answer (score 2):

cuando tu le dices a `cin` que lea un dato numérico y el usuario introduce un carácter, `cin` activa un flag de error y se bloquea hasta que dicho flag se resetee.

Para invalidar la entrada basta con que compruebes el flag de error y actuar en consecuencia:

```
double leerDouble()
{
    while(true)
    {
        double value;
        std::cin >> value;
        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "Dato no valido. Repita\n";

            // Reseteamos el flag de error
            std::cin.clear();

            // Limpiamos el buffer de entrada
            // (esto elimina el caracter que ha dado error)
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```