# Como hago que una estructura switch que esta revisando ints no acepte letras?

Tags: c, bucles, variables, switch

Tengo un problema con mi codigo, es un codigo que saluda

Pido que revise si la opcion escaneada fue 1 o 2:

1. Si fue 1, el programa va a volver a ciclarse.
2. Si fue 2, se despide y acaba.
3. Si no fue ninguna de estas deberia salir el mensaje de error

Mi problema es que cuando ingreso una letra, lo toma como un 1 por alguna razón  y vuelve a ciclarse cuando debería de salir el mensaje de error.

Que puedo hacer para solucionar esto, o que debo de cambiar? Si alguien podría corregirme seria de mucha ayuda :) Muchas gracias de antemano.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    
    int i,opc;
    i=0;
    
    printf("\t PROGRAMA SALUDO\n\nEste programa te saludara\n\n");
    
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    
    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nHola :D");
        sleep(3);
        printf("\n¿Deseas que se vuelva a imprimir la palabra? Presione 1 para si, 2 para no.\n\n ");
        scanf(" %i",&opc);
        
        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1: system("cls"); break;
            case 2: system("cls");
                    printf("Hasta luego c:");
                    sleep(3);
                    i++; break;
                       
            default:
                    system("cls");
                    printf("\nERROR \n\nPorfavor ingrese un valor valido, el programa terminara. "); 
                    sleep(3);
                    i++;
                    
        }
        system("cls");
        
        
        
    }while(i<1);


    printf("Presione <enter> para salir");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Mi problema es que cuando ingreso una letra, lo toma como un 1 por alguna razón y vuelve a ciclarse cuando debería de salir el mensaje de error.

Eso no es cierto.

Si tu configuras `scanf` para leer un número y el usuario introduce una letra lo que sucede es que **no se lee nada**. Así, en `opc` se quedará el valor que hubiese antes de llamar a `scanf`.

¿Y cómo se detecta el fallo de lectura?

Pues atendiendo a los valores devueltos por `scanf`:

```
int res = 0;
do
{
    res = scanf("%i", &opc);
    if (res == EOF)
    {
        puts("EOF found");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (res != 1)
    {
        puts("No se ha introducido un numero");
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }
} while (res != 1);

// Si llegas aqui, tienes un numero en opc
```

Quizás lo más raro de este ejemplo es el segundo bucle `while`

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Cuando se produce una lectura incorrecta, los datos mal introducidos se quedan en el buffer de entrada, por lo que en ocasiones es necesario eliminar manualmente dichos datos. Este bucle se encarga justamente de eso. Va leyendo y descartando caracteres de `stdin` hasta que llega a un final de línea o se recibe el caracter `EOF`

Comment: `scanf` retorna `EOF` cuando encuentra el final del stream. El estándar de C únicamente garantiza que el macro `EOF` expandirá a una expresión constante de tipo `int` con un valor negativo, no dice que el valor sera `-1`.  Seria mejor comparar `res == EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` es bastante malo para tomar las entradas del usuario. Aquí te topas con uno de los motivos:

```c
scanf(" %i",&opc);
```

El especificador de formato `%i` únicamente acepta números enteros decimales. Cualquier otra cosa que no se apegue al formato no sera leída a la variable.

Como te podrás imaginar, no siempre se puede confiar en que el usuario va a ingresar los valores en el formato correcto, así que es nuestro trabajo validar sus entradas.

En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489122/como-controlar-el-bug-para-cuando-se-ingrese-un-dato-de-tipo-char-cuando-el-pro/489146#489146) puedes ver el mismo problema en C++, es un problema común que te vas a topar en muchos lenguajes. En la respuesta que di a esa pregunta puedes ver las 2 formas en las que se suele resolver ese problema.

Para el método de "en caso de error, limpiando el stream", puedes referirte a la respuesta que coloco @eferion. Mi forma preferida es la de "leer una cadena y revisar esta cadena", ya que no pierdes la entrada del usuario en caso de que haya otra forma de recuperarse del error, o en caso de que quieras usar la cadena que ingreso el usuario para indicarle exactamente donde cometió el error (Útil sobre todo cuando son formatos complejos, imagínate si el compilador únicamente nos dijera "La sintaxis del código no es correcta", sin decirte que te comiste un `;`).

Separémoslo en 2 pasos:

1. **Leer una cadena:** Posiblemente sepas que puedes leer cadenas con `scanf` usando el especificador `%s`, pero nosotros no lo haremos de ese modo, ya que `%s` no acepta espacios ni tiene un limite en la cantidad de caracteres. Una mejor forma de leer cadenas es usando [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Le daremos al buffer un tamaño de 13 para que nos acepte hasta los enteros mas grandes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT 13

int main(void) {
    char text[MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT] = {0};
    fgets(text, MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT, stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

2. **Revisar esta cadena:** Para validar la cadena, vamos a usar una de las funciones de la familia de [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). `sscanf` recibe una cadena, y extrae de ella según el formato que nosotros le demos. Todas las funciones de la familia de `scanf` retornan un valor entero indicando la cantidad de argumentos que leyeron, así que podemos validar que el valor de retorno sea `1` para asegurarnos de que se leyó correctamente el numero entero:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT 13

int main(void) {

    char text[MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT] = {0};
    int  n = 0;

    printf("Ingrese un numero entero: ");
    fgets(text, MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT, stdin);
    if (sscanf(text, "%i", &n) != 1) {
        printf("El numero que ingreso no es un entero\n");
    } else {
        printf("El numero ingresado es: %i\n", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ahora únicamente nos quedaría pasarlo a un bucle para que le vuelva a pedir el numero al usuario si se equivoca:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT 13

int main(void) {

    char text[MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT] = {0};
    int  n = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Ingrese un numero entero: ");
        fgets(text, MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT, stdin);
        if (sscanf(text, "%i", &n) != 1) {
            printf("El numero que ingreso no es un entero\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("El numero ingresado es: %i\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Puntos extras si lo pasas a una función para facilitar el uso:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT 13

int get_int(const char* restrict prompt) {
    char text[MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT] = {0};
    int  n = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        fgets(text, MAX_INT_STRING_LENGHT, stdin);
        if (sscanf(text, "%i", &n) != 1) {
            printf("El numero ingresado tiene que ser un entero\n");
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int a = get_int("Ingrese el valor de 'a': ");
    int b = get_int("Ingrese el valor de 'b': ");
    printf("a = %i, b = %i", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```